# Searchpattern "?:"

Tags: regex, perl

What does this the following pattern  `?:` mean in regexp?
It should have something to do with searching for the n-ht occurrence of a pattern, isn't it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`?:` denotes non-capturing group:

`"Non-capturing groupings, denoted by (?:regexp), still allow the regexp to be treated as a single unit, but don't establish a capturing group at the same time`."

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Non-capturing-groupings

Answer (score 6):

When `?:` appears after a parenthesis, it makes the group non-capturing. The group is just used for applying quantifiers, or for grouping alternates, rather than to save the part of the string that matches that sub-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

**?:**  creates a phantom group. It means we cannot access that group. Ex.:

```
(Alan) (?:Messias) (Cordeiro)
```

We'll have 2 groups: 
`$1 = Alan` and `$2 = Cordeiro`

We do not have access the group between "Alan" and "Cordeiro".

Maybe you'll like this link to test regex: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Best regards

Comment: It's actually called a **non-capturing group**.